# MySQL Select from category in table y where Count (of the category's product from another table) is greater than zero

Tags: php, mysql

I am fetching list of categories using the code below

```
`mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);
$query_category = "SELECT category, categoryID FROM categories";
$category = mysql_query($query_category, $localhost) or die(mysql_error());
$row_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($category);`
```

Then i list the categories using the do while code: and within the code i count the number products under that category

```
<?php do { ?>
<li><?php  echo $row_category['category']; ?>" 


<span class="badge pull-right"><?php
$cadid = $row_category['categoryID'];
$resultcatd = mysql_query("SELECT  categoryID  FROM products WHERE   categoryID=$cadid "); 
$rowcatd = mysql_num_rows($resultcatd);  
echo $rowcatd;
?> </span>
</li>
<?php } while ($row_category = mysql_fetch_assoc($category)); ?>
```

The result becomes [image]

Now i dont want the categories that have zero products to be displayed: Is there someone with a better way of modifying the code 
`$query_category = "SELECT category, categoryID FROM categories";`
only to select categories that have products

Comment: look for keywords `GROUP BY` and `HAVING count(*) > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT category, categoryID 
FROM categories AS c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM products AS p
              WHERE p.categoryID  = c.categoryID )
```

or an `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT category, categoryID 
FROM categories AS c
INNER JOIN products AS p ON p.categoryID  = c.categoryID
```

or `IN` operator:

```sql
SELECT category, categoryID 
FROM categories 
WHERE categoryID IN (SELECT categoryID FROM products)
```

Comment: using your code it eliminates the zeros, great it works. is there a way i can order the list from the ones with highest number of products to those with least. and also to group the category names since some have the similar names

Comment: @KrushioVida Well, that's another question. It's a good practice here is SO to post it as a separate question rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

1 Replace ALL of your SQL with something like the following:

```
$query = "
SELECT c.category
     , c.categoryID
     , COUNT(*) total
  FROM categories c
  JOIN products p
    ON p.categoryID = c.categoryID
 GROUP 
    BY c.category_id;
    ";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

2 See about the deprecation of PHP's mysql_ API, and the importannce of prepared statements.

Comment: Your code works great even with the grouping but still another issue . can you order with number of products from high to low

Comment: @KrushioVida Go on. Have a go.