# How to displays total count of instructors for each department ? SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Here is the department table

```
department_id | department_name
1               computers
2               maths
3               physics
4               mba
```

Here is instructor table

```
instructor_id | department_id | name
1               1               abc
2               2               manu
3               2               raju
4               3               jaya
5               4               man
```

From above code how to displays total count of instructors for each department?

what will be the query?
Please help.

I'm doing it in codeigniter.

Comment: I tried `inner join` with `group by` but i'm getting error as `Column 'department_id' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: I believe you want something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35340801/mysql-select-from-category-in-table-y-where-count-of-the-categorys-product-fro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select d.department_id, count(*) as num_instructors
from departments d
     inner join instructors i on i.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(i.instructor_id) as `instructor_count`, d.department_name
FROM instructor AS i
JOIN department ON d.department_id = i.department_id
GROUP BY i.department_id"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to conceptualize from my solution below and see if it can help,

To avoid complication you could just go direct

```
<?php
//connection
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name") or die("Couldn't make connection.");

$computer_department_id = //the value
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  department_id FROM instructure_table WHERE department_id='$computer_department_id')");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($query); 

echo $total; //this one will display the total number of instructors in computer department
?>
```

Or if you like

```
<?php
//connection
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name") or die("Couldn't make connection.");

$computer_department = //the value
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT  department_id 
FROM instructure_table AS t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT department_id 
              FROM department_table AS d
              WHERE d.department_id  = t.department_id AND department_id='$computer_department')");
$total = mysqli_num_rows($query); 

echo $total; //this one will display the total number of instructors in computer department
?>
```

So if you place the query in the department line s

```
department_id | department_name
1               computers        //the query
2               maths            //the query
3               physics          //the query
4               mba              //the query
```

Even if the query for department is in a repeating region it would still work for you. regards